# What is SQL injection and best way to keep secure our database from it

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

I need to know what is SQL injection and best way to keep secure our database from it.

What technique we should follow to prevention from SQL injection attack.

Comment: I assume you mean SQL *injections*? What language/development environment are you using?

Comment: yes i mean the same...and am using dot net 3.5 with sql server 2008

Comment: conceptual and not specific, votes to move to programmers exchange.

Comment: Always relevant on this subject: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection ?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Injection is when a user inputs a query with actual SQL code that is passed to the database engine in order to cause havoc and execute unintended queries (most maliciously DDL statements, like `DROP TABLE`)

The technique to prevent SQL Injection is to use ***parameterized queries***.

```
insert into YourTable
values(@FirstVal, @SecondVal)
```

### This is BAD!!!!

```
SqlCommand SqlInjectionCandidate = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, MySqlConn);
SqlInjectionCandidate.CommandText = @"
    insert into YourTable
    values('" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "', '" + LastNameTextBox.Text + "')";
```

### The right way to do it

```
SqlCommand NoSqlInjection = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, MySqlConn);
NoSqlInjection.CommandText = @"
    insert into YourTable
    values(@FirstCol, @SecondCol)";

NoSqlInjection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstCol", YourFirstColVal);
NoSqlInjection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondCol", YourSecondColVal);
```